# What is meaning of expression (!array_name[index]) in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Can somebody help me understand that what is the meaning of the expression:

`if(!done[i])`

Where `done` is an array containing integer elements, `i` is the index which ranges from `0` to `500` and `done` is an uninitialized array and only the last element is explicitly filled as `0`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's same as `if( done[i] == 0 )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(done[i])
```

is the same as

```
if(done[i] != 0)
```

So,

```
if(!done[i])
```

is the same as

```
if(done[i] == 0)
```

Comment: what do you meant by if. Please explain what expression meant.

Comment: Read `if(!done[i])` as "if the `i`th element of the array `done` is 0". But, if you don't know what an `if` is, then its time to get hold of your textbook.

Comment: @Abhinav: seriously... you don't know what `if` means? RTFM

Comment: @Elias the reason i asked for the explanation is that the array is uninitialized.....

Comment: @Abhinav: Making use of an unitialized value is undefined behaviour, so if the array is really unitialized, the expression is meaningless.

Comment: @Abhinav: Still, the C standard is available in pdf format, and section 6.7 deals with initialization and declarations. It'll tell you what you can and cannot do, what you shouldn't do (ie causes UB), and what happens to an array that is declared like so `int foo[10] = {1, 2};` You say the last element is expressly initialized to 0, so saying `done` is completely uninitialized isn't entirely true, but for us to answer your question accurately, we'd need to see some more code. Basically: Check the standard and learn the basic syntax

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem , I honestly don't think a guy, who doesn't know what an `if` does, can understand anything from the standard. And nobody learns the basic syntax by looking at the standard.

Comment: @CoolGuy: That's why I mention them separately. Of course the standard isn't _"A beginners guide"_, but before asking what such a statement means, the OP should've bothered to read up on basic constructs like arrays and if's. If the OP doesn't know what an `if` is, how can he actually understand a comment like rici's (saying an uninitialized value is undefined behavior). No answer to this question that is any less then the first 2 chapters of K&R would be meaningful, that's why OP should start there