# if statement and puts()

Tags: c, if-statement, puts

Recently I have some across this solution on codeforces site. I couldn't understand the condition in the if statement and also the condition of the ternary operator in this question can someone please help me with this ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[1000]={0},ans,k;
    while((k=getchar())!='\n'){
      if(!a[k]){
          ans++;
          a[k]=1;
      }
    }
    puts(ans&1 ? "IGNORE HIM!":"CHAT WITH HER!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.hermetic.ch/cfunlib/ast_amp2.htm) for `&` operator

Comment: I've guessed that this is [tag:c] - but I shouldn't have had to. If I guessed wrong, please remove that tag and add the correct tag for your language.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , The code is in C. You guessed correctly.

Comment: Answer of first part here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194598/what-is-meaning-of-expression-array-nameindex-in-c/30194632#30194632

Comment: For the second part, look up on the bitwise AND operator.

Comment: @CoolGuy - the point is, there are a plethora of languages and just because there are a lot of strong signals here that say "C" to me, I don't like to presume that there's not another C-like language out there that I don't know of and that happens (for whatever reason) to have completely different semantics. That's why, despite my having added the tag, I always ask the OPs to confirm that the re-tagging is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bizarre piece of code, I'm not sure entirely *why* it does what it does but it's easy enough to understand from a technical viewpoint (i.e., *what* it does).

The `while` loop gets a series of characters from standard input and, for each unique one, adds one to the `ans` variable. The expression `!a[k]` will be true if `a[k]` is zero (they're all initialised to this state).

When that condition is true, `ans` is incremented and `a[k]` is set to `1`, meaning any more characters of that value will not affect the outcome (the condition won't ever be true again).

In terms of the `if` statement, the expression `ans&1` will be true if `ans` is odd (has its lower-order bit set).

So it appears it tells you to ignore people who have an odd number of unique characters in their names and talk to the others. Of course, the whole thing falls apart since you don't actually initialise `ans`, meaning it can be an arbitrary value (not necessarily zero) and that this program is therefore pretty much able to tell you whatever it wants.

Once you've *fixed* that little issue, I'll be happy to chat further - `paxdiablo` has eight unique characters. I should warn you in advance though, I'm not a "HER" :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[1000] = {0};
```

This is a way to fill `a[1000]` with `0`s.

If an array is partially initialized, elements that are not initialized receive the value 0 of the appropriate type (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589751/3235496).

---

```
if (!a[k])
```

checks if `k` is an "already seen character", thus skipping further increments of `ans`.

---

```
x & 1
```

Finds if `x` is even or odd (checking the last bit). You can take a look at [What is the fastest way to find if a number is even or odd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229107/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-if-a-number-is-even-or-odd) for further details.

So

```
puts(ans&1 ? "IGNORE HIM!" : "CHAT WITH HER!");
```

prints *IGNORE HIM* when `ans` is odd.